# PHP cURL post gives internal server error?

Tags: php, post, curl

I am trying to use a webservice, and do a post through PHP cURL. When I use the webservice through ie. fiddler the response is fine, but through my php script, I get nothing but 500 - internal server error. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Page: http://badmintonpeople.dk/DBF/Spiller/VisSpiller/#88555

use the button "vælg spiller" - there you have the webservice:
http://badmintonpeople.dk/SportsResults/Components/WebService1.asmx/SearchPlayer

In fiddler I get a fine response 200:
dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/885897/fiddler.jpg

But with the code below, I get nothing... Can anyone tell me why? :-/

```
$urltopost = "http://badmintonpeople.dk/SportsResults/Components/WebService1.asmx/SearchPlayer";
    $data = array (
      "callbackcontextkey" => "7CF866FEDDD42B1529DAED8272DA83AF72EFBB896E3176EFB70CD34D02A81BF647D420A3F880C10178E804AC21CA4999",
      "selectfunction" => "SPSel1",
      "name" => "",
      "clubid" => "1600",
      "playernumber" => "",
      "gender" => "",
      "agegroupid" => "",
      "searchteam" => false,
      "agegroupcontext" => 0,
      "tournamentdate" => "",
    );                                                                   

$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('http://badmintonpeople.dk/SportsResults/Components/WebService1.asmx/SearchPlayer');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);  
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

UPDATE:
Response is this:
{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}

Bonus info. A friend of mine made the post work in seconds in .NET with this code, but I can not imagine, that PHP can't do this job?

.NET Console Application

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string URI = "http://badmintonpeople.dk/SportsResults/Components/WebService1.asmx/SearchPlayer";
        const string myParameters = "{'callbackcontextkey':'874DB247192F515BC3735AD164D4350C6DD5A0CFD186112C97A41B3B9FE97F81637FBEF0AEDF4A5939481BAFFFBD0A99','selectfunction':'SPSel1','name':'','clubid':'1600','playernumber':'','gender':'','agegroupid':'','searchteam':false,'agegroupcontext':0,'tournamentdate':''}";

        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
            string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have PHP error_reporting turned on? You should see related PHP error.

Comment: Is the line after the posted code smth like `$result = curl_exec($ch)` ?

Comment: There is no error in the PHP script, so I get no errors. The only thing I get is the added response from the service :-/

Comment: Just change Content-Type to text/plain... so you get more details. (cause it isnt json) `Content-Type: text/plain`

Comment: using text/plain just gives internal server error :

Comment: There was an error reflecting type 'SportsResults_WebApp.SportsResults.Components.GetTournamentEventsResult'. ---> There was an error reflecting field 'Events'. ---> There was an error reflecting type

Comment: 'SportsResults_WebApp.SportsResults.Components.GetTournamentEventsItem'. ---> Cannot serialize member 'SportsResults_WebApp.SportsResults.Components.GetTournamentEventsItem.fields' of type 'SportsResults_WebApp.SportsResults.Components.GetTournamentEventsOptionField[]', see inner exception for more details. ---> SportsResults_WebApp.SportsResults.Components.GetTournamentEventsOptionField cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.